# need help with xampp virtual host

Tags: xampp, virtualhost

I am using XAMPP, Apache 2.2.17. I have added virtual host but my virtual host and localhost both point to the same location. Here is my code in httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost www.domain.tld:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/workspace/testsite"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp"
   ServerAlias localhost
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

With the above code, I get testsite with www.domain.tld so that is good. But If i type localhost, it will go to testsite  as well. If I move  ahead of test site then localhost goes to localhost good and www.domain.tld goes to localhost too. I tried different setting for localhost as like

```
<VirtualHost *>
<VirtualHost localhost:80>
```

and removing *.domain.tld from domain.tld but nothing works. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own answer: The following code fixed the problem

```
<VirtualHost *:80> <--- * fixed the problem, apache 2.2 doc does say it must match www.domain.tld, which caused problem for other Virtual hosts
ServerName www.domain.tld
ServerAlias domain.tld 
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/workspace/patriot2"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp"
   ServerAlias localhost
   ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: could you please take a look at my problem bro https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173872/virtual-host-cannot-create-with-xampp-server ?

Answer (score -1):

please change your ServerName from virtualhost to a local IP address such as 127.0.0.2.

ServerName domain.tld is an example of using "domain.com" where .tld is replaced by .com for your domain.

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1 before but did not work. Tried it again, did not work + tried <VirtualHost 127.0.0.2:80>, did not work.