# XAMPP Virtual Host Not Loading

Tags: xampp

I am trying to set up a local test server where I can test my code before pushing it live, although I have a little problem, I have set the httpd-vhosts.conf like this:

Comment: See http://www.tildemark.com/setting-up-virtual-hosts-with-xampp-running-on-windows-xp/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7270787/need-help-with-xampp-virtual-host-resolved

Comment: I have, but I can't get it to work.

http://localhost - works fine
http://mw1dev - does not load at all :(

Comment: Is mw1dev really at 172.0.0.1, or did you mean 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `127.0.0.1           mw1dev`

in the host file.

After starting of Apache (and MySQL), go to the address  localhost or  127.0.0.1 in your browser and examine all of the XAMPP examples and tools.