# Virtual Host cannot create with XAMPP server

Tags: apache, drupal-7, xampp, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I add the following codes in httpd-vhost.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/mmcast"
ServerName mmcast.dev
 <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/mmcast">
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Although I can run the Apache and MySQL in XAMPP but I cannot call my vhost. 
 I got "Unable to connect" error in when I call mmcast.dev in browser. 

Do I need to change `<VirtualHost *:80>` into 81 ? Because I change **Listen 81** in httpd file. But, I tried to change 80 to 81 but it still does not work.

In **httpd.conf** file, I change like this but it does not work.

```
<Directory />
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In **hosts** file,

```
127.0.0.1       mmcast.dev
```

Only `http://localhost:81/mmcast/` works. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: if you are using port 81, then yes 80 should be changed to 81 and make sure you call your domain `mmcast.dev:81` by including the port number

Comment: @hmd, bro I got it now... Thank you very much. :) I didn't add port number. But adding port number does not associate with virtual host naming in drupal? I mean .. I 'm afriad that portnumber include everywhere whenever I call the image location path in drupal bro

Comment: No, port number needs to be included in all request, if it is not default port 80. I haven't worked with drupal but it should be the same!

Comment: ok bro. Thanks a lot for your answer . :)

Comment: welcome, hope it is solved :)

Comment: bro @hmd, I would like to ask one question. I got Connection is not secure problem in my virtual host website. How can I solve this bro? In httpd-ssl file, port number is 4433 .  <VirtualHost _default_:4433> bro.

Comment: have not worked with SSLs, you need to install SSL certificate first. You will have to purchase it from your host or a third party I believe. Default port for SSL is 443 though.

Comment: okie bro. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Very first confirn you have an entry in hosts file -

```
127.0.0.1   mmcast.dev
```

Second, check `httpd.conf` file - there are multiple `< directory` tag and if necessary make all `Require all granted`

Third, in `httpd-vhost.conf` file write bellow lines

```
# you can put any port whatever you feel comfortable! I normally use 127.0.0.1:144 and counting for every project
Listen 127.0.0.1:81 
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81>
    ServerName mmcast.dev
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcast"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mmcast">
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Fourthly, **RESTART XAMPP Server**. and try in browser `https://127.0.0.1:81`